# How to get jquery array from html each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
   <li>listitem1</li>
   <li>listitem2</li>
   <li>listitem13</li>
</ul>
```

I have something like this on HTML file. So how can I get that each list item in my jQuery file as array

like this

```
var asmg = ["listitem1","listitem2","listitem3"];
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

use the [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and `.get()` to process a plain array.

```js
var asmg = $( "li" )
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
 }).get();
 
 console.log(asmg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>listitem1</li>
  <li>listitem2</li>
  <li>listitem13</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `foreach` loop :

```js
function getArray(ul){
  asmg = [];
  ul.find('li').each(function(){
    asmg.push($(this).text());
  });
  return asmg;
}

console.log(getArray($('ul')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>listitem1</li>
  <li>listitem2</li>
  <li>listitem13</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
$(function(){
  var asmg = [];
  $("ul > li").each(function(i, li){
    asmg.push($(li).text());
  });
  console.log(asmg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>listitem1</li>
  <li>listitem2</li>
  <li>listitem13</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla JavaScript to achieve this:

1. Select all the `li` elements

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('li')
   ```
2. unpack them in an array

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('li')]
   ```
3. map this array to get the text content of each `li` item.

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map(e => e.textContent)
   ```

Here is the code:

```js
const li = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map(e => e.textContent)

console.log(li)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>listitem1</li>
  <li>listitem2</li>
  <li>listitem13</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var asmg = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).map(e => e.textContent);
```

```js
var asmg = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).map(e => e.textContent);
console.log(asmg);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>listitem1</li>
  <li>listitem2</li>
  <li>listitem3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var varObject = $('ul li').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

   //converting to array 
   var aiMsg = $.makeArray(varObject);
```

this code works for me.

thanks for all the answer